# How to draw the following figure in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I'd like to reproduce this figure. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}  % pgfplots -> for plotting
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b1) at (2,-0.3);
    \coordinate (c1) at (12,-1);
    \coordinate (d1) at (10.5,-1.2);
    \coordinate (e1) at (2,-0.6);
    \draw[line width=0.5mm,color=blue!80!green!70,fill=blue!80!green!10] (a1)--(b1)--(c1)--(d1)--(e1)--(a1);

    \coordinate (a2) at (-3,2.5);
    \coordinate (b2) at (-2.3,2.4);
    \coordinate (c2) at (4,0.8);
    \coordinate (d2) at (9,0.4);
    \coordinate (e2) at (12.5,2.2);
    \coordinate (f2) at (-2.9,2.6);
    \draw[line width=0.5mm,color=blue!80!green!70,fill=blue!80!green!10] (a2)--(b2)--(c2)--(d2)--(e2)--(f2)--(a2);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (b2)--(0.4,-0.8);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (-2.8,2.3)--(-0.5,-1);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (0,0.05)--(2.5,1.15)--(4,-0.44);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (b1)--(4.2,0.77);

    \draw[line width=0.3mm,purple,fill=purple!50] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(4.50,0.74) (4.73,0.61) (4.95,0.58) (5.18,0.52) (5.41,0.57) (5.63,0.55) (5.86,0.56) (6.08,0.47) (6.31,0.51) (6.54,0.49) (6.76,0.40) (6.99,0.43) (7.22,0.41) (7.44,0.46) (7.67,0.35) (7.89,0.25) (8.12,0.27) (8.35,0.28) (8.57,0.18) (8.80,0.4)};
    \draw[line width=0.3mm,purple,fill=purple!50] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(4.60,-0.46) (4.83,-0.40) (5.05,-0.38) (5.28,-0.34) (5.51,-0.44) (5.73,-0.4) (5.96,-0.45) (6.18,-0.37) (6.41,-0.41) (6.64,-0.45) (6.86,-0.55) (7.09,-0.5) (7.2,-0.48) (7.4,-0.55) (7.7,-0.5) (7.9,-0.63) (8.22,-0.6) (8.45,-0.69) (8.67,-0.56) (8.90,-0.76)};

    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (4.35,0.75)--(5.2,-0.35);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (4.3,-0.44)--(5.25,0.53);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (5.4,0.57)--(6.2,-0.37);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (5.45,0.-0.41)--(6.3,0.5);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (6.35,0.5)--(7.2,-0.49);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,red] (6.8,-0.54)--(7.3,0.43);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Test plotting; scramjet engine.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And my figure looks like this

[image]

But I can't figure out how to reproduce those orange region on the right. Besides, I can't closely match the colors.

I know my approach is very naive. But any suggestions? Thanks.

**Update:**

Following @Symbol1 with some tweaks, here is what I got for now. Does not look as good as original one though...

[image]

BTW, does anyone know how to reproduce those original blues? They look more comfortable to me.

Comment: what does the figure represent?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @Thruston This is a scramjet engine.

Comment: @AndréC I've just updated. Please take a look. Thx.

Comment: I may not know various mathematical notations used on this site, but I know a jet inlet when I see it!  I can hear the *sounds of freedom* now. +1

Comment: The blue is `\colordef{jet-blue}{HTML}{BDD7EF}`.

Comment: @Symbol1 Cool, this is the color! Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a *shading* that goes from dark orange to dark yellow, and to white.
Something like the following

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,fadings}
\colorlet{jet-orange}{orange!80!black}
\colorlet{jet-yellow}{yellow!80!black}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \shade[left color=jet-orange,right color=jet-yellow]
        (0,0)rectangle(5,5);
    \shade[left color=jet-yellow,right color=white]
        (5,0)rectangle(10,5);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To produce the fuzzy/noisy effect, add shadings/fadings with higher frequency.

```
\tikz{
    \shade[left color=jet-orange,right color=jet-yellow]
        (0,0)rectangle(5,5);
    \shade[left color=jet-yellow,right color=white]
        (5,0)rectangle(10,5);
    \clip(0,0)rectangle(10,5); % clip the circles that bleed
    \foreach\i in{1,...,10}{% add 10 fuzzy circles
        \shade[inner color=jet-orange,outer color=jet-yellow,
            path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent,opacity=1/5]
            (\i/2,rnd*5)circle(1+rnd*2);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks nice. But how can I incorporate this with those wiggly boundaries?

Comment: @SJH look at the `\clip` command [15.9 Clipping and Fading](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)

Comment: @AndréC I see. Any suggested command for generating those wiggly boundaries? I used `plot [smooth]` in my original code, but it's not quite handy.

Comment: There are third-party GUI tools for TikZ so you can play with Bezier curves. Once you are satisfied with the path you export them verbally like `(1,2)..controls(3,4)and(5,6)..(7,8).......`. Other methods I know are just computationally intensive.

Comment: @Symbol1 Yeah, that's what I am doing for now. The new figure is attached. It doesn't look as good as original one though....

Comment: So the blue is #BDD7EF. And for the burning gas, I suppose you can play with more high-frequency shadings and fadings. Perhaps add some strips or ellipse. Perhaps q/201830 would inspire you. Or search for the word *Moire pattern*. And also look at `bilinear interpolation` in the TikZ doc.